# How to play audio data in HTML5 using audio tag?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

I have web service. I fetch the audio data from web service using nodejs and postman.

When I look at the postman, postman is showing me data like this :

�����BE���F9�����(� C�x5�]�L��4a̡�=0 h!��bZ��bQ-��?�]���Û�M�S���  .....(and it extends like this).

I am not sure what kind of data is this.

On the client side I use Angular 8. I wrote some code in Angular. Here is my code of Typescript.

```
this.service.getPhoneSoundData("ID of sound data...").subscribe((data: any) => {      
    const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data.query_result)], {type: 'audio/mp3'});
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.source = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);

});
```

And also this is the HTML code which I wrote:

```
<audio controls="controls" id="audio">
   Your browser does not support the tag. 
   <source id="source" [src]="source" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

When I execute the codes, I get the following error:

> GET blob:http://localhost:1001/0705bca8-9299-44ad-be7b-81f17b65ffc9 net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE

I used a lot of solutions and I didn't succeed. Could you help me find the correct solution for this issue?

Comment: How do u take your data from server? as file or base64?

Comment: @pc_coder ı take data as file from the server.

Comment: Then give your api url directly to src

Comment: When I give api url directly to src, I get an error. The error is: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. Api has self signed certificate. I can fetch sound file from localhost but in real world, ı get an error. @pc_coder